# How do I create a multidimensional vector/array of different types?

Tags: c++

I know that to create a multidimensional vector you'd need to write it like this

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > name;
std::vector<int> firstVector;
firstVector.push_back(10);
numbers.push_back(thisVector);
std::cout << numbers[0][0]
```

Output would be 10.

However I am trying to create a table of three different types. The first column would be a string, the second would be ints, and the third would be doubles.

Output of this table would look something like this

```
One     200    5.1%
Three    10    1.4%
Nine   5000   10.8%
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I followed your explanation, but it *sounds* like what you really want is a vector of structures:

```
struct whatever { 
    std::string first; // The first column will be a string
    int second;        // ...the second would be ints
    double third;      // ...and the third would be doubles.
};

std::vector<whatever> data;
```

As far as your output goes, you'd define an `operator<<` to handle that:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, whatever const &w) { 
     os << std::setw(10) << w.first 
        << std::setw(5) << w.second 
        << std::setw(9) << w.third;
     return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can use a `vector` of `tuple`s:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, double>> var;

    var.emplace_back("One", 200, 5.1);
    var.emplace_back("Three", 10, 1.4);
    var.emplace_back("Nine", 5000, 10.8);
}
```

Use **[`std::get<N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)** for compile-time indexing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest encapsulating the data into a class and than jsut using a vector of that class.

(probably won't compile as is)

```
class MyData 
{
public:
    std::string col1;
    int col2;
    double col3;
};

...
std::vector<MyData> myData;
MyData data1;
data1.col1 = "One";
data1.col2 = 10;
data1.col3 = 5.1
myData.push_back(data1);
```

This is much more convenient to work with since now when you need to print out your collection you are only iterating over one set of objects and you don't need to worry about indexing or accessing into a complex vector of vectors or tuples.